# How to generate a Hash key for Facebook Integration

Tags: java, android, android-intent, command-prompt

I am doing Facebook Integration how to generate a Hash key ..please help me

```
1.how i am going to generate Facebook hash key using Command prompt,

2. confusing i checked so many tutorials but not getting help me
```

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/ hi try this tutorial it will help u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto your jdk/bin path on cmd promt
and download openssl and unzip in c drive.
then write  `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Go to window -> preference -> android -> build so, you will get your pcs md5 and sha1  fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

just change the path "~/.android/dubug.keystore" as per in your pc

it will ask you for a password

enter the password as android then  will see the hash key printed on the terminal